# write hex string as bytes to socket java

Tags: java, sockets

I have a string of hex values that I am trying to write to a socket as bytes.

```
String confDeliv = "\\x7E\\x01\\x00\\x20\\x37\\x02\\x03\\xF2\\xD5";
```

I have tried doing this to try and solve my problem

```
byte [] Delivery_Conf = {(byte)0x7E, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x20,
                             (byte)0x37, (byte)0x02, (byte)0x03, (byte)0xF2, (byte)0xD5};
```

But I have yet to succeed to write it to the socket. I don't get any errors but when I send it to the device it doesn't do what I need it to do I have tried two different ways of doing this.

Try 1:

```
DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());                                           //69.171.154.64

    for (int i = 0; i < Delivery_Conf.length-1; i++) {
        dOut.writeByte(Delivery_Conf[i]);
    }
dOut.flush();
```

This method I used when I but the values into a byte array.

Try 2:

```
DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());                                           

            dOut.writeBytes(confDeliv);
            dOut.flush();
```

This is the method I used when I tried sending it as the string but still no luck. I am able to make the device work when I use python using its byte string.

eg.

```
confDel = b"\x7E\x01\x00\x20\x37\x02\x03\xF2\xD5"
```

I think java changes something when I send it and I think that is why I can get it to work with java. I have looked around for while but I do not seem to find anything that will help me with my problem.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what is 'wrong' with the received string on the device side?

Comment: Thats what I am trying to find out. @uniknow

Comment: When I send the bytes I need to have the '\x7E' I have to have the backwards slash or else it doesnt work how can I add that into my code? to make that work?

Comment: Have you tried to encode/decode the string you have with `Hex` of apache commans and see what the result is? PS: are you expecting at device side a string or an byte array?

Comment: @uniknow Anything as long as I get the full command through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the following:

```
byte [] Delivery_Conf = {(byte)0x7E, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x20,
                         (byte)0x37, (byte)0x02, (byte)0x03, (byte)0xF2, (byte)0xD5};
// ...
dos.write(Delivery_conf);
```

The version you had writing a byte at a time should work but it's inefficient, and it's possible that the device has timing constraints.

The version using the `String` isn't correct. Adding another backslash to make `\x` compile is not a correct solution: you should change `\x` to `\u00` throughout. Throughout the string, that is, of course.

Comment: What do you mean "change \x to \u00 throughout." I cant at that to my byte array because it mistakes it for a string.

Comment: I am speaking of 'the version using the `String`'. Please read what I actually wrote.

Comment: My bad. Thank you for your response.

Comment: How can I write this more efficiently?@EJP

Comment: @BSD_ You can't. There is no inefficiency here. In a real program fixed data like that would be `static final` of course.

Comment: Hey Thanks for this answer fixed this problem a long time ago haha! Turned out to be the command that I was sending was actually wrong but thank you for your help! @EJP